# Bootstrap: Multiple carousel on one page - multiple images in each

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have implemented multiple Bootstrap carousels on the same page each having a unique id. However, these carousels are added dynamically i.e. based on user actions(images uploaded).

I want each carousel to hold 3 images at a time. I am trying to accomplish this using jQuery using this link: http://www.bootply.com/DKihet1ZM9

While this works for a single carousel, is there any way I can extend it to all of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution - turns out what I was doing was correct. It was a rather silly error. I had not fixed the height of the inner carousels and hence when adding multiple images they were overflowing.